# Angular Material elements/fonts are too big for desktop use

Tags: angular-material

I have a website that is using Angular material. I like elements and everything except default font sizes and elements are huge. To see website in acceptable scale me or my users have to zoom out at least 75% on the desktop and majority of my users are desktop users. Is there a way to specify in angular material to use smaller fonts, elements, etc?

Answer (score -1):

Before you attempt anything, make sure you are using the correct fonts and font sizes by following the [typography guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/typography#usage).

Font sizes can be adjusted by [customizing the typography](https://material.angular.io/guide/typography#customization). Changing the size of elements is technically possible, but to do it you would need to override the styles for every Angular Material component - so it is highly impractical.

Also, component sizes as well as font sizes are determined by the Material Design specifications, so changing things means you are no longer properly following the specification, and IMO you would end up with a bad looking web site (at least bad looking in terms of following Material Design).

Comment: Well, website doesn't look good anyway since the fonts are ridiculously huge and users have to zoom out to 75% for the website to look acceptable.  I tried to follow typography guide but it looks like it doesn't change anything (I tried to switch to 8px fonts). When using typography do I need to decorate each element with those body1 classes referred in the override or there is a way to force apply those changes to the website in one shot?

Comment: You can do it in one shot, but that means creating your own custom typography config and applying it to Angular Material as well as your app as is described in the link. You only need to add `class="mat-typography"` to your `<body>` tag. I have to say, however, that this "too big" experience you are describing isn't normal - I haven't run across that complaint before. Note that desktop and browser settings can affect this - On Windows 7 for example the text size setting will affect this. Curious - does the Angular Material demo site also appear too big or is it just your app?

Comment: Yes, demo site is the same size as well

Comment: I think it's all too big too. I have a resolution of 1920 x 1080 and it's alright, but I have other people using my Angular web-app and they all can't see stuff because it overflows off their screen and is all giant. Everyone but me... their resolutions are lower, so it looks all goofy. I think it's all ridiculously large, especially on computer monitors with resolutions lower than mine.

Answer (score -1):

in your main css file

add following

```
html {
    font-size: 62.5% // adjust the size with percentage here.
}
```

and i recommend using `em` and `rem` for font-sizing

let me know if it didn't worked, i might provide another solution